# SQLite C++ Compare two tables within the same database for matching records

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I want to be able to compare two tables within the same SQLite Database using a C++ interface for matching records. Here are my two tables

Table name : temptrigrams

```
ID          TEMPTRIGRAM       
----------  ----------  
1           The cat ran        
2           Compare two tables       
3           Alex went home
4           Mark sat down      
5           this database blows
6           data with a
7           table disco ninja 
++78
```

Table Name: spamtrigrams

```
ID          TRIGRAM       
----------  ----------  
1           Sam's nice ham        
2           Tuesday was cold       
3           Alex stood up
4           Mark passed out      
5           this database is
6           date with a
7           disco stew pot
++10000
```

The first table has two columns and 85 records and the second table has two columns with 10007 records.

I would like to take the first table and compare the records within the TEMPTRIGRAM column and compare it against the TRIGRAM columun in the second table and return the number of matches across the tables. So if (ID:1 'The Cat Ran' appears in 'spamtrigrams', I would like that counted and returned with the total at the end as an integer.

Could somebody please explain the syntax for the query to perform this action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `join` query with an `aggregation`.  My guess is that you want the number of matches per `trigram`:

```
select t1.temptrigram, count(t2.trigram)
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.temptrigram = t2.trigram
group by t1.temptrigram;
```

If you just want the number of matches:

```
select count(t2.trigram)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.temptrigram = t2.trigram;
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble following your example. I've edited my original post to include the table names. Could you please reiterate with making reference to the table names/column names? At the moment, I get the following error 'IntelliSense: expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type'.

Comment: Nevermind - I managed to get it working! Thanks again Gordon.